# Google Drive Integration with AS3 Application

Tags: actionscript-3, api, google-drive-api

How to integrate Google Drive with AS3 application? How to use Google Drive API?

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation made by Google. First, you might want to read the SO FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

I learned following some time ago, so feel free to correct me if some of my info is outdated.

First of all, you will have to deal with **`OAuth2`** before you can start doing anything specific for `Google Drive`.

Then, `Google Drive API v2` is not supported for `ActionScript`.
It means that there are no ready lib to use.
Instead of directly making actions with files(like it is done for supported languages), you will have to read the documentation and **build necessary HTTP requests on your own**.

Reading `javascript` documentation is the optimal variant because they often build requests manually there, and actionscript has some things in common with javascript.

**Be warned**: documentation contains some errors, so you will have to **compare documentation example requests with your own requests**

You may find some opensource projects for `Google Drive API v1`(when I last check them, this API version was still supported(but declared as deprecated), but those projects didn't work for unknown reason.

Since that time some projects for APIv2 may have appeared, but I don't know anything about them. I had to write the the code on my own.